# How can I write a query let value in a column for year and year -1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with this table:

```
id   | Data       | OtherData  | Year |
-----+--------+----------------+------- 
001AA  | 156540     | 195896     | 2014 
405BB  | 111342.54  | 79263      | 2014 
001AA  | 42550      | 216417     | 2015 
056CC  | 26900      | 352194     | 2014 
023DD  | 23524      | 139124     | 2014 
023DD  | 21659.80   | 108143     | 2015 
405BB  | 111212.65  | 111449     | 2015 
056CC  | 64871.95   | 541478     | 2015
```

I would like this:

```
id   | Data 2014  | Data 2015   |
-----+------------+-------------+- 
001AA  | 156540     | 42550       | 
405BB  | 111342.54  | 111212.65   |   
056CC  | 26900      | 64871.95    | 
023DD  | 23524      | 21659.80    |
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: look at `Pivot`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE WHEN` with `MAX` function.

```
SELECT id,
      MAX(case when [Year]= '2014' then Data end) as 'Data 2014',
      MAX(case when [Year]= '2015' then Data end) as 'Data 2015'     
FROM T
GROUP BY id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3df7e7/1)

Answer (score 2):

You have yo pivot data!

```
SELECT id, [2014], [2015]
FROM YourTable AS Dt
PIVOT (MAX(Data) FOR Year IN ([2014], [2015])) AS PVT
```

See: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You're very welcome. If my answer was helpful, please, accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pivot`

```
Select id, max([2014]) as [Data 2014], max([2015]) as [Data 2015] from tbl as tm 
pivot (max(data) for [year] in ([2014],[2015])) as pvt 
group by id
```

EDIT:

You'll need dynamic query for that.

```
declare @myYear as smallint;
declare @myYearN_1 as smallint;
set @myYear = 2015;
set @myYearN_1 = 2014;

Set @query = 'Select id, max(' + @myYear +') as [Data_N], max(' + @myYearN_1 + ') as [Data N-1] from tbl as tm 
pivot (max(data) for [year] in (' + @myYear,@myYearN_1 + ')) as pvt 
group by id'

execute(@query)
```

Comment: thanks for code, but  I wanted to use pivot with parameters? How should i do? I posted the code below... thanks

Comment: data type of year is smallint

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use **pivot** with parameters but it faults: Error Message: Failed to convert from nvarchar to smallint...Incorrect value "@myYear" specified in the PIVOT operator.

```
    declare @myYear as smallint;
    declare @myYearN_1 as smallint;
    set @myYear = 2015;
    set @myYearN_1 = 2014;
    Select id, max(@myYear) as [Data N], max(@myYearN_1) as [Data N-1] from [tbl] as tm 
    pivot (max(data) for [year] in ([@myYear],[@myYearN_1])) as pvt 
    group by id
```